# How to Remove single character from a Mixed string In Python

Tags: python, optimization, replace

[image: Table]

I have one table (Please Ref Image) In this Table I want to remove "A" char from  each Row How can I do in Python.

Below is my code using `regexe_replace` but code is not optimised I want optimised code

```
 def re(s):
      return regexp_replace(s, "A", "").cast("Integer")

    finalDF = finalD.select(re(col("C0")).alias("C0"),col("C1"),
                        re(col("C2")).alias("C2"),
                        re(col("C3")).alias("C3"),col("C4"),
                        re(col("C5")).alias("C5"),
                        re(col("C6")).alias("C6"),col("C7"),
                        re(col("C8")).alias("C8"),
                        re(col("C9")).alias("C9"),col("C10"),
                        re(col("C11")).alias("C11"),col("C12"),
                        re(col("C13")).alias("C13"),
                        re(col("C14")).alias("C14"),col("C15"),
                        re(col("C16")).alias("16"),col("C17"),
                        re(col("C18")).alias("18"),
                        re(col("C19")).alias("C19"),col("Label"))
    finalDF.show(2)
```

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: If I were you, I wouldn't define a `re` function. It will clash with the  [regular expression operations module](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/re.html) name. Could you give more details about, for example, where your input data comes from ?  Is that from a database ? Where is `regexp_replace` is defined ? Ideally can you give a complete program we could understand ?

Answer (score 2):

Why regex? Regex will be over kill.

If you have data in format you have given, then use **replace function** as below:

**Content of master.csv:**

```
A11| 6|A34|A43|
A11| 6|A35|A44|
```

**Code :**

```
with open('master.csv','r') as fh:
    for line in fh.readlines():
        print "Before - ",line
        line = line.replace('A','')
        print "After - ", line
        print "---------------------------"
```

Output:

```
C:\Users\dinesh_pundkar\Desktop>python c.py
Before -  A11| 6|A34|A43|
After -  11| 6|34|43|
---------------------------
Before -  A11| 6|A35|A44|
After -  11| 6|35|44|
---------------------------
```

**Code with replacing 'A' from complete data in in one shot (without going line by line)**

```
with open("master.csv",'r') as fh:
    data = fh.read()
    data_after_remove = data.replace('A','')
    print "Before remove ..."
    print data
    print "After remove ..."
    print data_after_remove
```

**Output:**

```
C:\Users\dinesh_pundkar\Desktop>python c.py
Before remove...
A11| 6|A34|A43|
A11| 6|A35|A44|
After remove ...
11| 6|34|43|
11| 6|35|44|

C:\Users\dinesh_pundkar\Desktop>
```